# Ejercicio para salir de python apretando SI o No

Tags: python-3.x

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando quiera salir de python y ponga "si" se imprima "Nos veremos luego, adiós" y cuando ponga "No" se imprima "Que agradable que decidas quedarte, sigamos..."

he realizado el mismo ejercicio con donde las respuestas son 1)si 2)no y me sale perfectamente. 
¿Cual es mi error con las letras? ¡Gracias de antemano!

```py
si = True
no = False
print("¿Quieres salir de python?")
typed_answer = input("Responda si o no: ")
if typed_answer == si:
        print("Nos veremos luego, adiós.")
        quit()
if typed_answer == no:
        print("Que agradable que decidas quedarte, sigamos...")

#Acá esta el mismo ejercicio hecho con números

##print("¿Quieres salir de python?")
##typed_answer = int(input("Responda 1 o 2: "))
##if typed_answer == 1:
##        print("Nos veremos luego, adiós.")
##        quit()
##if typed_answer == 2:
##        print("Que agradable que decidas quedarte, sigamos...")
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

```py
si = True
no = False
print("¿Quieres salir de python?")
typed_answer.lower() = input("Responda si o no: ") # si aca le agrego el .lower() me sale el un error "can't assign to function call"
if typed_answer.lower() == si:
        print("Nos veremos luego, adiós.") #Lo que quiero que se ejecute
        quit()
if typed_answer.lower() == no:
        print("Que agradable que decidas quedarte, sigamos...")#Lo que quiero que se ejecute
```

Comment: Estás comparando `typed_answer` que es una cadena, con las variables `si` o `no` que son booleanas. Esa comparación no está bien (aunque no es un error de sintaxis, no se comporta como esperas). Tienes que comparar lo que el usuario teclea con la cadena `"si"` o `"no"`. Para permitir variaciones puedes hacer algo como `typed_answer.lower() == "si"` para pasar a minúsculas la respuesta del usuario antes de comparar, y así permitirle que escriba "SI", o "Si" además de "si".

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda. Te comento que no he podido solucionar agregandole el ".lower()" ya que no imprime lo esperado

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta, poner un apartado "actualización" y en él el código que tienes ahora?

Comment: Ahí lo agregué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
print("¿Quieres salir de python?")


answer = input().lower

if answer() == "si":

    print("Nos veremos luego, adiós.") 

if answer() == "no":

    print("Que agradable que decidas quedarte, sigamos...")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias evidentemente el problema lo tenia era el .lower y las comillas en el si y no de las condicionales.